# JAVA: Unformed Sprite When trying to Read SpriteSheet

Tags: java, javax.imageio, sprite-sheet

So Im a beginner experimenting with ImageIO. Can someone tell me why im getting this pixelated-incomplete sprite?
Here's the code

```
public BufferedImage getImage(String location)
{
    try 
    {
        File file = new File(location);

        image = ImageIO.read(file);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.err.println("It don't work!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

And Im using this method to display it

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(getImage("Numbers/icon0.png"), 0, 0, 32, 32, null);
    repaint();
}
```

And here's what it gives me

[image: And here's what it gives me]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the first (single) cell of your sprite, you probably meant to write:

```
g.drawImage(getImage("Numbers/icon0.png").getSubimage(0, 0, 32, 32), 0, 0, null);
```

Notice the `getSubimage(x, y, w, h)` part, to get a single cell.

If you wanted to draw the entire sprite sheet, you could use:

```
g.drawImage(getImage("Numbers/icon0.png"), 0, 0, null);
```

Your original code will draw *the entire sprite sheet*, rescaled to 32x32.

---

PS: You should probably not invoke `repaint()` from the `paint` method, as that will create an endless repaint loop. If you want your component to repaint, use some kind of timer that repaints your component at fixed intervals.

PPS: You should probably not do I/O (ie. read the image) inside the paint method, because any I/O operation may take time and make your UI sluggish and unresponsive. It's also unnecessary, as the sprite sheet does not change every time you repaint. Instead, read the image up front, and only draw it in the `paint` method.